# Passing a variable number of arguments to Apex class methods

Tags: method

In a method in apex class, is it possible to give variable number of arguments.
`method1(arg1,arg2,...)`
Will this be working fine ??

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatley this isn't possible. You can overload methods, so if there's only ever going to be 2, 3 or 4 arguments say, you could do:

```
void method1(String arg1, String arg2)
{
  method1(arg1, arg2, '', '');
}

void method1(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
{
  method1(arg1, arg2, arg3, '');
}

void method1(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3, String arg4)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Alternatively, assuming your arguments are all of the same type (which seems likely in such a use case), you could just use a list:

```
void method1(List<String> args)
{
}
```

Even if they're different types you could cast to strings to put in the list, or use `List<Object>`; but that could get messy and it depends on what it is you're doing.

Comment: If you go down the road with a List<Object>, then i would suggest to resort to Map<String, Object>, which would at least allow named parameters and allows you to retain some safety, which does not only rely on the position of the argument...